# Where are the `HttpContext.IsWebSocketRequest` property and the `HttpContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest` method?

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm trying to get a simple "Hello World" type WebSocket server running on my Mac using Visual studio for Mac OS X.

Where are the `HttpContext.IsWebSocketRequest` property and the 
`HttpContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest` method? The documentation appears to say they are in HttpContext inside the System.Web dll but I've referenced that (as well as System.Net) and Visual studio can't find them.

Is there something I'm missing or have forgotten?

This is the code I've that's giving me problems.

```
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Net.WebSockets;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(HandleWebSocket);
        else
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
    }
```

The sample I'm following is: https://github.com/paulbatum/WebSocket-Samples/blob/master/AspNetWebSocketEcho/EchoHandler.ashx.cs

Comment: Make sure your using .NET 4.5

Comment: `mcs --version` tells me i'm using "Mono C# compiler version 4.8.0.0", Could it be only supported on windows?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember is not supported yet: http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.5&profile=4.5&assembly=System

You can use one of the many third-party components available for Mono. I develop and maintain one of them https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener